Posts Cross-Appearing in the Wrong Directories - Gatsby
I am building a blog with 2 different blog subdirectories. One is /blog/{blog_slug}/ and the other is /projects/{blog_slug}. My folder structure is as follows:
blog/
    blog1/
         index.mdx
         hero.jpg
    blog2/
          index.mdx
          hero.jpg
projects/
        project1/
         index.mdx
         hero.jpg
        project2/
          index.mdx
          hero.jpg
.
.
.

src/pages/
         blog/
             index.js
             {mdx.frontmatter___slug}.js
         projects/
                 index.js
                 {mdx.frontmatter___slug}.js

And my directories look like:
localhost:8000/blog/blog1
localhost:8000/projects/blog1
localhost:8000/blog/blog2
localhost:8000/projects/blog2
localhost:8000/blog/project1
localhost:8000/projects/project1
localhost:8000/blog/project2
localhost:8000/projects/project2

Of course, the /blog/ subdirectory shouldn't contain the project1 post, but it does, and it will throw a 404 error when you go to it because I have filtered the GraphQL query.
What should I do?
I guess the naming of the {mdx.frontmatter___slug}.js has something to do with it.
I have considered trying to change the "slug" frontmatter of one type of post to something like "project_slug" and then change the JS file to {mdx.frontmatter___project_slug}.js, but idk if it works, and I have it as my last resort.

Why are files being put into the wrong directories in the first place? Fix that problem.

@Bamar Which files ?

The files containing the posts that you say are in the wrong directories. Maybe I don't understand the problem you're having. If it's something specific to gatsby configuration, I can't help you there.

Don’t use file based routing in this case. You can’t specify multiple directories without falling back to gatsby node. https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#createPages
